# How to customize the layout for a specific watch size using Xcode's Vary for Apple Watch button in the Watch Interface storyboard

Tags: xcode, apple-watch, xcode-storyboard

I'm trying to set up a layout specific to Apple Watch 38mm but can't get it to work.

I tried clicking on the "Vary for Apple Watch 38mm" button, changing a constraint in the Attributes Inspector (view size height), and then clicking on "Done Varying". When I then look at the other device sizes, they all have the change I thought I was making to the 38mm device only. Can anyone offer some guidance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same issue which brought me to your post. I don't know how the  "Vary for Apple Watch 38mm" works, but I found another way.

In the attributes inspector, there's "+" signs all along the left side. If you click one, you'll get a drop-down with different watch sizes. This way you can customize a given attribute for a watch size. Hope this helps.

Comment: if you have eg "Vary for Apple Watch 38mm" selected, and change the layout in the storyboard (eg by dragging and dropping a new label onto the interface, or adjusting the margins manually), then those changes happen only for the 38mm watch.